# Regular expression to check if the first character of a string is '+' and the rest are numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression to check if the first character of a string is '+' and the rest are numbers. eg: +919447733140

Comment: a quick google search could have got you this answer.

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do what you want `/^\+\d+$/`

You can use it like this:

```
function isPlusNum(num) {
    return /^\+\d+$/.test(num);
}
console.log(isPlusNum('+5555'); //returns true;
console.log(isPlusNum('-5555'); //returns false;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a regex that covers it:

```
/^\+\d+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

as the others said, a plain regex of `/^\+\d+$/` does that.

however, before you continue, I feel compelled to preach for a moment.

> This is for validating mobile numbers (along with country code,eg:
>   +919447733140)

Unless you're telling them specifically that they can only have that format for their phone numbers, you're probably going to run into issues with validating. not only that, there are much bigger, better regex's out there for matching the larger variety of phone numbers (with ext, punctuation, international variants, etc). And even so, many people simply believe the best way to collect a phone number is to not imply any regex restrictions at all -- just let 'em give you what they want to give you. its your choice! `//end rant. :)`

Answer (score 0):

So, with `/^\+\d+$/` you have your expression, but as Kristian said: people do tend to put in numbers with spaces, dashes or even dots and comma's. Besides, an input like 00919447733140 would be valid, too. The double 0 at the beginning is equal to the `+` sign.

If I were you, I'd turn to something along these lines:

```
pn = '00919-4477 33140';
pn.replace(/[^+0-9]/g,'').match(/^(0{2}|\+)\d+$/)[0];//<--00919447733140
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex which will help you to validate Indian mobile number

```
(\+91|0091)?[7-9][0-9]{9}
```